# Disabling the browser's  'ctrl+s' default function

Tags: jquery, hotkeys

I use [jQuery-hotkeys](http://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys)

And the following code:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+s', function(){$('#save').click()});
```

but I cannot disable the browser's default behavior. How do I disable it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you return false from your handler to disable "bubbling up" the event.  So:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+s', function(){$('#save').click(); return false;});
```

... but it may be browser specific.  From [your link](http://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys):

> Firefox is the most liberal one in the
>   manner of letting you capture all
>   short-cuts even those that are
>   built-in in the browser such as Ctrl-t
>   for new tab, or Ctrl-a for selecting
>   all text. You can always bubble them
>   up to the browser by returning true in
>   your handler.
>
> Others, (IE) either let you handle
>   built-in short-cuts, but will add
>   their functionality after your code
>   has executed. Or (Opera/Safari) will
>   not pass those events to the DOM at
>   all.
>
> So, if you bind Ctrl-Q or Alt-F4 and
>   your Safari/Opera window is closed
>   don't be surprised.

Comment: CTRL+S is disabled ..It's good...This will also disable all textbox in the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

this works in FF too:

```
$(document).bind('keydown keypress', 'ctrl+s', function(){
  $('#save').click(); 
  return false;
});
```